# How to load a local directory in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I want to load a directory in actionscript. To do that I use the File class but sadly it doesn't work.

Here is what I did. First I created the directory in the applicationStorageDirectory using this code:

```
var root:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(UIDUtil.createUID());
root.createDirectory();
```

After that I dispatch an event so that the application copies some files into that folder. To do that I use the method File.copyToAsync (that works, so this is not the problem). When all files are copied to that directory I try to load that directory using the File call again. The reason I want to do that is, that I need the content/data as a byte array. The data property of the File class is only set when the load method is called successfully before.

Since the directory is in the application storage directory (the url property of the file object has this content: app-storage:/FF011DBC-2E92-46A8-D5F8-29FE1DD8FA7A) I thought just calling the load method would work. I was wrong... Although the documentation of that method says I can just call that method when the application runs in AIR and the file to load is inside the application sandbox, I get the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2038: File I/O Error.
at flash.filesystem::File/resolveComponents()
at flash.filesystem::File/resolvePath()
    ...
```

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? Is it even possible to load a directory using the File class? Or does that error occur because the isDirectory flag is set to true in the file  object?

kind regards
Markus

Comment: Not sure this is supported, nor that I understand this statement: "The reason I want to do that is, that I need the content/data as a byte array" ... what do you need in the form of a byte array? The list of files in the directory or the contents of each file in the directory? If you need the latter, you should get a directory listing and read in each file individually.

Comment: I need the latter, actually I need to write a zip file with all files that are in that directory. So I thought/hoped that I could just use the data property of the directory File object. If that is not possible I need to go through all the files in the directory to get the data of each file individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a `File`, when pointing to a directory, does not contains the data of the files contained inside it. You would have to use `File.getDirectoryListing()` to loop over all files the folder, and append their bytes to the ZIP archive separately. Don't forget to check if you come across sub-directory...

You can check this [link](http://pradeek.blogspot.ca/2009/05/creating-zip-files-with-adobe-air-with.html) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Ok thank you. Since now you and Sunil told me that loading all files separately is the way to do it, I will accept your answer.